# Erro de logica shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Estou querendo printar na tela uma mensagem de acordo com a hora atual do dia porem sempre cai no else, qual seria o erro? ja to a 1h e não entendo qual o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seguinte comparação é desnecessária e nunca será verdadeira:

```
elif [ "$HORA" -ge 12 -a "$HORA" -lt 06 ]
then
    echo "Boa Noite!";
else
```

Veja só a solução:

```
#!/bin/bash

HORA=$(date +%H)

if [ "$HORA" -ge 6 -a "$HORA" -lt 12 ]
then
     echo "Bom dia!";
elif [ "$HORA" -ge 12 -a "$HORA" -lt 18 ]
then
    echo "Boa tarde!";
else
    echo "Boa noite!";
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

tenta isso, mas não tenho tanta certeza.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 clear
 HORA=$(date +%H)

 if [ "$HORA" -gt 05 -a "$HORA" -lt 12 ]
 then
     echo "Bom dia";

 elif [ "$HORA" -gt 11 -a "$HORA" -lt 18 ]
 then
     echo "Bom tarde";

 elif [ "$HORA" -gt 17 -o "$HORA" -lt 6 ]
 then
     echo "Bom noite";
 fi
```

acho que o problema ta na hora, se você esta executando isso de noite, não tem como a hora ser maior que 18 e menor que 6

Comment: Esse código não vai funcionar entre `00:00hrs` e `06:00hrs`!